# NtOpenFile and NtCreateFile function hooking without detours

Tags: visual-c++

i want to hook NtOpenFile function and NtCReateFile function together in Ntdll dll in c++ and i use traditional method which is written in API Hooking with MS Detours in codeproject but it is crashed what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use IAT (Import Address Table) hooking instead. You can find a ton of examples and tutorials in the internet. This method is reliable than detours, but not powerful as detours; since its unable to install a wide-hooking in the address space. You need to hook all module's IAT you want to do a call interception.

Comment: can you please suggest me some paper about iat hooking or some project that is done with iat hooking or a link about that?

Comment: Try http://xevia.webege.com/old/atoray/2010/06280.php with translator (Google, Bing, etc.).